# how to create a wrapper to launch junit classes from jmeter

Tags: java, selenium, junit, jmeter

I have junit class written for selenium for automatic test cases.

I would like to create a wrapper to run it with jmeter to do performance tests.

Could you give me an example of a code?

Comment: have you tried using JUnit Request http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request ?

Comment: I need to pass the username and password and ip variable for testing

Comment: I tried to reword your question to make it easier to read. Please review my changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [Selenium client](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) libraries to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html) (basically copy all the dependencies of your project into "lib" folder of JMeter)
2. Copy .jar(s) with your tests into  "lib/junit" folder of JMeter
3. Restart JMeter to pick the .jars up
4. Add [JUnit Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) sampler to your test
5. You will be able to choose your class(es) and method(s) from the dropdowns

   [image: JMeter Selenium Integration Junit]

More information: [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter)